Sharepoint different permission between site and document library
have a sharepoint site let's say :
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/test
this site has :
a) home page
b) document library
c) subsite
and the subsite has :
d) home page ane document library
e) document library
then i have 2 security group coming from my on premise AD.
Let' say

Group1
Group2

I'd like that
Group1
sees : a/b
Group2
sees : a/(c)/d/e
Both groups need to access on the main entry :
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/test
On Main Site

I gave site access to group1 and group2
on document library i gave visual access only to group 1

On Subsite

i gave site access to group2
doc library i gave access to group2

When i log with a user of group 1 I correctly access a/b and i see c subsite menu, but nothing is shown
When i log with a user of group 2 i see also b, and i should not.
Am i doing something wrong ?
Is it possible to achieve what i need ?
Thanks in advance
